# Eclipse 4 RCP Vogel tutorial: Exit menu item does not appear

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, menuitem, e4

OS X 10.7.5,   Eclipse 4.3 Kepler build ID 20130919-0819, Java 1.7.0_51

I'm following along the [Vogel tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html), and I've hit a snag that I can't figure out.  I'm in the [section covering commands and handlers](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html#tutorial_uicomponents) menu items, etc.  I've created the five commands and handlers that he suggests, but one of them, Exit, does not show up on in my menu.  I have the two top-level menus, File and Edit, and Edit contains all three of the entries that it's supposed to.  The File menu, however, has only the Save entry. AFAICT (and I've looked it over many times) all of my entries are as the tutorial suggests.  I looked at the XMI view, and everything there looks ok, by which I mean that there's nothing obviously different with the Exit entries compared to those for Save.

If I start with an empty File menu and try to add Exit (leaving out the Save), the entire File menu does not appear on the menu bar.

Can you suggest what might be wrong, or what to look for?

tia, g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse handles OS X specially and moves a few menu items around to match the OS X standards. The Exit menu item will be in the 'Application' menu (the furthest left with your application name).

Comment: Yes indeed it does.  Thanks.  I presume the displayed name for that entry is fixed.  Is that right, or can it be changed?

Comment: The name for the menu is the value of the `name` attribute of the `<product>` element in the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.products` extension point.

Comment: ok, I see.  But it seems that the system makes the menu entry "Quit <product>".  The word "Quit" seem to be fixed.  I have no idea why anyone would want to change that behavior,  and it's undoubtedly good practice to adhere to the conventional behavior, but it is different than menu items that are not shipped to the OS.  For items that Eclipse deals with, the developer can choose the entry to say whatever he or she wishes.  I just point this out to highlight the difference between the two situations in case anyone ever reads this.  (Assuming I understand correctly.)